# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' / No module named 'requests'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cannot seem to import `beautifulsoup` or `requests` however everything seems to be in order from what I have read online. I'm not sure what I have missed.

**PATH:**

```
C:\Users\ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
C:\Users\ross\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

**Script:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

**`pip3 install` output:**

```
Requirement already satisfied: bs4 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (2.22.0)
Requirement already satisfied: beautifulsoup4 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from bs4) (4.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.9,>=2.5 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2.8)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (2019.6.16)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (1.25.3)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from requests) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: soupsieve>=1.2 in c:\users\ross\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages (from beautifulsoup4->bs4) (1.9.2)
```

**`python --version` output:**

```
Python 3.7.4
```

**`python -m pip freeze` output:**

```
astroid==2.1.0
beautifulsoup4==4.8.0
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
colorama==0.4.1
idna==2.8
isort==4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy==1.3.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pylint==2.2.2
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.9.2
urllib3==1.25.3
wrapt==1.11.0
```

**`import sys; print(sys.path)` output:**

```
['C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\Downloads', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\ross.watson\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

**`pip --version` output:**

```
pip 19.2.1 from c:\users\ross.watson\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

**Final Edit**

I'm an idiot, I remove the 3.7.2 64 bit version and it worked fine. The issue was having multiple versions. Not sure why the install would install 2 different version for 32/64 bit. Thank all for you help.

Comment: before importing, can you run `import sys; print(sys.path)` and include the output in the question?

Comment: try installing it like this: `py -m pip install requests`

Comment: Added details to question.

Comment: Is this like, more than 1 python version installed?

Comment: check `which pip`, and `which python` to see if you are installing the package to the proper python installation

Comment: I see some differences in paths - one python is `\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37`, second is in `local\programs\python\python37-32`. Do you have multiple version of Python installed - e.g. Jupyter?

Comment: potentially, how do I check if I have Jupyter. I just ran the installer from python site.  In programs & features I have `Python 3.7.4 (32-bit)` and `Python 3.7.2 (64-bit)`. I changed the path to be `Python\Python37` and still the same issue.

Comment: @zwep not sure how to how to run which pip. is that in cmd or .py?

Comment: @Ross `which` is a unix command, so you're not able to run it on windows. There is a similar command called `where`, which should also tell you where the executable given a command is living. But hey, glad you solved it. If your python runtime has a hard time finding packages that you think should be installed, the first step is always asking the python program where it's looking for packages, i.e. `sys.path`.

Comment: Btw, you can turn your final edit into an answer and accept it after a day. Be sure to include how you made sure that the wrong python version was called and what exactly you needed to do in order to resolve the issue.